# VBA Excel file is saved next to the newly created folder but not inside

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to save my file in the folder created one level up ion directory.

Everything works fine apart from the file saving.

My code looks as follows:

```
Set apfwb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & "\Resources\template V0.2.xlsm")
Dim apffr As Worksheet
Dim myFileName As String
Dim Path As String, FinalPath As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim fldrname As String, fldrpath As String

Path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FinalPath = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Path, InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\"))
myFileName = "Pack v0.2.xlsm"

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
fldrname = "APF-MDU"
fldrpath = FinalPath & fldrname
FinalFile = fldrpath & myFileName
If Not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then
fso.createfolder (fldrpath)
End If

If FileLen(fldrpath & myFileName) > 0 Then
MsgBox ("File arleady exists!")
Exit Sub
Else
Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fldrpath & myFileName, 
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

How could I save it inside the newly created folder?

Comment: What's `newly created folder` ? I haven't seen any code to create a directory in your snippet.

Comment: Already added to the code

Comment: Try `pplication.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fldrpath & "\" & myFileName, ... `

Comment: Your `fldrpath` is missing a "\" as far as I can see since you're adding "APF-MDU", so `fileName:= fldrpath & "\" & myFileName"` should fix it

Comment: No, it doesn't as the Error 1004 keep appearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create Workbook From Template

- Not tested!

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
'Dim apfwb As Workbook ' declared previously???
'Dim PathName As String ' declared and populated previously???

Dim apffr As Worksheet ' ???
Dim fso As Object
Dim fldrname As String, fldrpath As String
Dim myFileName As String, FinalPath As String

fldrname = "APF-MDU"
myFileName = "Pack v0.2.xlsm"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

fldrpath = PathName & "\" & fldrname & "\"
If Not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then fso.CreateFolder fldrpath
FinalPath = fldrpath & myFileName

If fso.FileExists(FinalPath) Then
    MsgBox ("File arleady exists!")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set apfwb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & "\Resources\template V0.2.xlsm")
    apfwb.SaveAs Filename:=FinalPath, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End If
```

**An Improvement (Standalone)**

```vb
Sub CreateFromTemplate()
   
    Const ROOT_PATH As String = "C:\Test"
    Const TEMPLATE_SUB_FILE_PATH As String = "Resources\Template V0.2.xlsm"
    Const NEW_FOLDER_NAME As String = "APF-MDU"
    Const NEW_FILE_NAME As String = "Pack v0.2.xlsm"

    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim nFolderPath As String:
    nFolderPath = fso.BuildPath(ROOT_PATH, NEW_FOLDER_NAME)
    
    If Not fso.FolderExists(nFolderPath) Then fso.CreateFolder nFolderPath
    
    Dim nFilePath As String:
    nFilePath = fso.BuildPath(nFolderPath, NEW_FILE_NAME)
        
    If fso.FileExists(nFilePath) Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & nFilePath & """ already exists!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim tFilePath As String:
    tFilePath = fso.BuildPath(ROOT_PATH, TEMPLATE_SUB_FILE_PATH)
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(tFilePath)
    
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=nFilePath, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    
    'wb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This for example (leveraging more of the fso methods):

```
    Const FLDR_NM As String = "APF-MDU"
    Dim wb As Workbook, nfPath As String, nf As Object
    Dim fso As Object, pf As Object 
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook   'for example
    
    Set pf = fso.GetFolder(wb.Path).ParentFolder 'one level up
    
    nfPath = fso.BuildPath(pf.Path, FLDR_NM)
    If Not fso.FolderExists(nfPath) Then fso.CreateFolder nfPath
    
    wb.SaveAs FileName:=fso.BuildPath(nfPath, wb.Name), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: This oned is wrong as the main file is saved in that folder not the output file.

Comment: @Geographos - hence the "for example" comment.  I'm not trying to reproduce your exact workflow but just demonstrate a basic approach.

Comment: I've tried to use my new file name, but I failed. For the following code: myFileName =  Pack v0.2.xlsm"

 wb.SaveAs fileName:=fso.BuildPath(nfPath, wb.myFileName), _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: `fso.BuildPath(nfPath, myFileName),`

Comment: `myFileName` is a standalone variable and not a property of `wb`

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention an error occurring prior to your comment so I took your code to testing and after changing a few things, it works.

Full code with least amount of changes:

```
Sub test()
    Dim apfwb As Workbook, PathName As String 'added for testing
    PathName = "C:"                           'added 
    Set apfwb = Workbooks.Open(PathName & "\Resources\template V0.2.xlsm")
    Dim apffr As Worksheet
    Dim myFileName As String, FinalFile As String 'Added FinalFile to declaration
    Dim Path As String, FinalPath As String
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fldrname As String, fldrpath As String
    
    Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    FinalPath = Left(Path, InStrRev(Path, "\")) 'Use the variable
    myFileName = "Pack v0.2.xlsm"
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    fldrname = "APF-MDU"
    fldrpath = FinalPath & fldrname
    FinalFile = fldrpath & "\" & myFileName 'Don't forget the & "\"
    If Not fso.FolderExists(fldrpath) Then
        fso.CreateFolder (fldrpath)
    End If
    
    If Len(Dir(FinalFile)) > 0 Then 'use Dir instead with the variable you just filled
        MsgBox ("File arleady exists!")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        apfwb.SaveAs fileName:=FinalFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
        'Use the variable
    End If
End Sub
```

- The takeaway here is, use the variables you're creating to not do twice the work for no pay-off.
- `Dir` is easier to check if a file exists, if it doesn't exist, I was getting an error with your line `If FileLen(fldrpath & myFileName) > 0`.
- Indent your code for readability :)

Let me know if it doesn't save in the correct path.

Comment: I will be back to your code later. Thank you for your help.